# parent page grabbing wrong url for child pages - get_page_uri($pageChild)

Tags: child-pages, pages

I have a landing page that pulls in an excerpt, title and thumbnail of its children. It works, except the title (which is the page title) link is doubling up the parent folder in the url it creates. like this:
www.site.com/restaurant/restaurant/mcdonalds. I'm not great at PHP and I can't figure out why it's doubling on the title and not the thumbnail. How can i alter this to only pull in the parent once?

```
  if ( is_page( 'restaurants' ) ) {
                    $pageChildren = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $post->ID, 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'hierarchical' => '0', 'exclude' => '1453' ) );
                    if ( $pageChildren ) {
                    foreach ( $pageChildren as $pageChild ) {
                    echo '<div class="restaurant-landing"><h2><a href="' . get_page_uri($pageChild) .'">' . $pageChild->post_title . get_the_post_thumbnail($pageChild->ID).'</a></h2>';
                    if ($pageChild->post_excerpt){
                    echo '<p>'.$pageChild->post_excerpt.'</p></div>';
                    }
                    }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you look into the html in the browser, you should see that the function is outputting a relative link uri;

is there any reason why you are trying to use [`get_page_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_uri) instead of [`get_permalink()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink) ?

Comment: you know what.. you're right. I don't know. that totally worked. :) Thank you!